# Area Lit with Volume Lighting

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, volumetrics

My understanding is that if a light is brighter, it will light a larger area. (Like a point light.) If I try this with a volume light, it seems to only light an area proportional with its scale, not its brightness.

Here is an example:

Emission set to 10:

[image]

Emission set to 100:

[image]

Emission set to 1000:

[image]

The .blend I used to test this [is here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AqKxXPZzafVQlroPbl6WaoSUqbJQ7A).

Is there a way to light a larger area without changing the scale of the volume?

Answer (score 4):

The light does travel farther, its just that volume lights take longer to resolve. If you up your samples you should see the light extend further. You could also use a standard emission shader without volume which will render faster.

[image]